# java.io.IOExceptoin Keysize too big in Windows 2003 Server

Tags: java

I have a Java project created in Netbeans in Ubuntu that uses Java keystore. When I run the jar file in Ubuntu there is no problem and it works fine. When I run the same jar file in Windows 2003 server I get the following error

```
java.io.IOException: Keysize too big
 at sun.security.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad
 at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad
 at java.security.KeyStore.load
```

After searching the web I found it is because of Out of Memory error. But tried some fixes. Nothing works. Any Idea on how to solve this problem.

It looks like some environment issue. The keystore file was created in linux using keytool. 
if I use keytool in windows to list the keys like this 
$keytool -list -keystore file

I get keytool java.io.IOException Keysize too big.

If I create a keystore in windows no error in the application, but the problem is I will have to use the same keystore. it has both public and private key.  The same keystore file works perfectly in Linux.

Comment: What key size are you trying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At some point, the `JavaKeyStore.engineLoad` method is doing something like this (the following snippet is coming from [OpenJDK](http://www.docjar.org/html/api/sun/security/provider/JavaKeyStore.java.html)):

```
// Read the private key
try {
  entry.protectedPrivKey = new byte[dis.readInt()];
} catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
  throw new IOException("Keysize too big");
}
```

To my surprise, it catches an `OutOfMemoryError` an rethrows it as an `IOException` ... OK, it's *their* code.

So, the error comes from the attempt to create a real big byte array. I doubt, that the actual key is that big, so it looks to me that the inputfile is either corrupt or misinterpreted so that the method tries to create that array with a value which isn't the actual size of the key in bytes.

Comment: Wow, Interesting response. I agree with you completely. I tried copying the file again and again from my linux laptop to the windows 2003 machine. I am not sure if the file is corrupted. But I am sure keystore file itself has a problem. Why does the file work perfectly in linux while it does not in windows. It was created using keytool.

Comment: Hmm, the cause for throwing IOException when the reason likely is a corrupted file is that `KeyStore.load` (whose implementation calls this) allows only IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException and CertificateException - and the documentation says: ***IOException** - if there is an I/O or format problem with the keystore data*. They should include the wrong keysize at least in the error message, though.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. I might be silly. I want to close this issue. The problem is I was transferring the keystore file using normal ftp. keystore or key file should not be transferred using TEXT MODE. you can use scp or ftp. That was my mistake and that messed up the keystore file. I didnt know it actually. The reason is in TEXT MODE file is copies line by line where some characters in the keystore files will be interpretted wrongly Eg \n etc.

I used scp and it worked fine. Thanks for your comments guys. and thanks to IRC java community.

Comment: Yeah, in text mode the FTP programs try to convert between different line-ending modes, so one 10 byte on the unix side gets converted to one 10 and one 13 byte on the windows side.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to increase memory for your app then run it with `-Xmx256m` option (or change the 256m to whatever you want to have there). `M` or `m` for megs, `G` or `g` for gigs. Good luck.

I remeber getting strange OOM exceptions when I trying to decode for example invalid zip files. So make sure the keystore is there and has the expected format. Maybe use some well-tested tool for this purpose. If the tool throws OOM then there might be something wrong with the keystore itself and not with your code.

Comment: Jan, I tried this. Its all invein. I think even though it looks like memory issue its not actually I guess. Why is that keystore files created in windows alone works. while the keystore file created in linux has this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it's caused by OutOfMemoryError. Maybe you have the unlimited strength policy file installed on the Ubuntu server and not on the Windows one. This policy file is needed in order to have strong cryptographic keys.

See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html (at the end of the page) to download it and see if it makes a difference (there is a README inside the zip file explaining how to install it).

Comment: I think you are right, its not because of OutOfMemoryError. I have updated my query check it out. Its some format of the keystore i guess. Let me try your solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Start the jar with the following option

```
java -Xmx512M -jar <jarname>.jar
```

to investigate a little why is the OutOfMemoryError you can use

```
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError // Flag in the JVM to get a dump heap information to disk.
```

Comment: It may not be memory problem.. I think the problem is the keystore file itself. if i use the command $keytool -list -keystore file

I am getting the same exception keytool java.io.IOException Keysize too big.